# Cannot get salutation field from contact via REST API

Tags: rest-api, contact, .net

I am using [force toolkit for .net](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) to get contact fields. I make a soql query like:

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Salutation FROM Contact
```

One of my contact has a salutation field set to `Mr.` like this screenshot:

[image: salesforce web page]

After I edit the contact, the query result however, returns a null salutation field in the json string:

[image]

**Question:**

What am I missing to successfully get (or set) the contact salutation field?

**Edit:**

After a few hours, I tested the same query. Finally I got the `salutation` field `Mr.` listed in the same contact record.

Very strange. Might be a Salesforce related problem?

Comment: Have you tried with the most recent api version (later than v36.0)?

Comment: I just verified with v36.0 and later and could get the desired results, i.e., could get `Salutation` field. You may like to verify if the data as in screenshot you have here was saved or not, i.e., if the record was saved with the`Salutation` value or not.

Comment: @JayantDas I checked the reoird. It surely has a `salutation` value `Mr.` saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems unlikely that you are being impacted by the [SOQL Query - Not returning salutation field in some scenarios](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EtSAQA0) known issue in this case as you aren't using a relationship query to retrieve the Contacts Salutation field.

It's more likely that either:

1. The salutation field hasn't actually been updated successfully in Salesforce, or
2. Something is caching the prior value.

I used the following console application to verify that the Salutation can be changed and then retrieved successfully using the .NET toolkit.

```
using Salesforce.Common;
using Salesforce.Common.Models.Json;
using Salesforce.Force;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        const string clientId = "ABCDEFiTxZANhwHQt0.omitted.pQqhw5m7nxK6aBx1234567890";
        const string clientSecret = "12345678901234567890";
        const string username = "john@example.com";
        const string password = "omitted";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                const int SecurityProtocolTypeTls11 = 768;
                const int SecurityProtocolTypeTls12 = 3072;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= (SecurityProtocolType)(SecurityProtocolTypeTls12 | SecurityProtocolTypeTls11);

                var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
                await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(clientId, clientSecret, username, password);

                var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);

                string newSalutation = "Mr.";

                var contact = new Contact() {Salutation = newSalutation };
                string contactId = "0037000001ngFB6AAM";

                SuccessResponse updateResponse = await client.UpdateAsync("Contact", contactId, contact);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(updateResponse.Success);

                var updatedContacts = await client.QueryAsync<Contact>(string.Format("SELECT ID, Salutation from Contact where ID = '{0}'", contactId));
                foreach(Contact updatedContact in updatedContacts.Records)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(updatedContact.Salutation == newSalutation);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Salutation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With that I was able to successfully change the Salutation from **Dr.** to **Mr.** and back again.

Comment: Thank you. The value might be cached for this record? Hope salesforce fix this problem soon.